# Failed to run rsync, return rc 5888 (23), on ReadyNAS host and OSX remote

Tags: linux, macos, backup, rsync, nas

I have a ReadyNAS 104 which I use to backup different computers with rsync.

Copy from my Ubuntu servers works fine, but fails on OS X.

I have rsync 3.1.2 from homebrew on OS X.

The ReadyNAS does connect and copy some but always end with this error:

(The individual files/folders may change between backups, but same pattern)

```
Backup Finish Time: Sat Feb 20 2016  7:08:53
Backup Status: Fail: failure during copy.

Failed to run rsync, return rc 5888 (23)
'rsync' command returns rc=5888

cannot delete non-empty directory: Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTPlaygroundCommunication.framework/Modules
could not make way for new symlink: Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTPlaygroundCommunication.framework/Modules
cannot delete non-empty directory: Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/etc
could not make way for new symlink: Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/etc
could not make way for new regular file: System/Library/Automator/Encode Media.action/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/main.nib
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/ColorSync/Calibrators/Display Calibrator.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/BuildingPane.nib
could not make way for new regular file: System/Library/ColorSync/Calibrators/Display Calibrator.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/BuildingPane.nib
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/Resources/da.lproj/GLUT.nib
could not make way for new regular file: System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/Resources/da.lproj/GLUT.nib
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/ScreenSaverEngine.nib
could not make way for new regular file: System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/ScreenSaverEngine.nib
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/DatabaseProcess.app
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/DatabaseProcess.app
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/NetworkProcess.app
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/NetworkProcess.app
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/PluginProcess.app
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/PluginProcess.app
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebProcess.app
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebProcess.app
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitPluginHost.app
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitPluginHost.app
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessagesHelperKit.framework/PlugIns
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessagesHelperKit.framework/PlugIns
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessagesKit.framework/XPCServices
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessagesKit.framework/XPCServices
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/XPCServices
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/XPCServices
cannot delete non-empty directory: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symptoms.framework/Frameworks
could not make way for new symlink: System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symptoms.framework/Frameworks

sent 828,217 bytes  received 431,182,180 bytes  504,390.42 bytes/sec
total size is 558,385,868,958  speedup is 1,292.53
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [generator=3.1.1]
```

Is this an error of the host or the remote?

The actual command line the ReadyNAS uses is as following:

```
rsync -v -8 --timeout=1800 --recursive --links --times --omit-dir-times --devices --specials --one-file-system --modify-window=1 --owner --group --no-acls --no-perms --exclude .snapshots root@192.168.1.101::root /Backup/OSX
```

Comment: If you want to delete the items then `--delete-excluded` would get rid of those on the dest (where the error occurs) since they likely are not on the source and why it complains.

Comment: well thats the thing. I don't want to delete files from the destination even if they are no longer on the source.

Comment: In that case then maybe a protect filter might be what you could set on  those directories.. (eg. `--filter='protect System/**/*'`)... try using it with a `--dry-run` ...